# Solr Spell Checking returns suggestions with exact match, case sensitive

Tags: solr, spell-checking, search-suggestion

I am working with Solr SpellChecking. 
I use the schemaless mode, default configuration is data driven and I indexed a csv file, inside the file content, there is a column Nationality, and some column values are **S**ingapore.
Then I query spell check and I got result

```
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">7</int>
    </lst>
    <result name="response" numFound="0" start="0"></result>
    <lst name="spellcheck">
        <lst name="suggestions">
            <lst name="singapor">
                <int name="numFound">1</int>
                <int name="startOffset">0</int>
                <int name="endOffset">8</int>
                <int name="origFreq">0</int>
                <arr name="suggestion">
                    <lst>
                        <str name="word">singapore</str>
                        <int name="freq">104</int>
                    </lst>
                </arr>
            </lst>
        </lst>
        <bool name="correctlySpelled">false</bool>
        <lst name="collations">
            <lst name="collation">
                <str name="collationQuery">singapore</str>
                <int name="hits">104</int>
                <lst name="misspellingsAndCorrections">
                    <str name="singapor">singapore</str>
                </lst>
            </lst>
        </lst>
    </lst>
</response>
```

I want the exact result with case sensitive **S**ingapore, not **s**ingapore.

```
<str name="word">Singapore</str>
```